# How can I combine two animated GIF images into one?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing, gif

I have two animated `.gif` files. Is it possible to combine these two `.gif` into one `.gif`?

Comment: try reading this site it will helps you [multiple gif](http://ezgif.com/help/merging-gifs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gifcomb

```
       A  program to combine 2 GIF images of exactly the same size
       into one.  The color maps are merged, but the result may not exceed 256
       colors.   A  boolean  mask GIF file can be used to set which pixel from
       two images to use at each location.   Otherwise  any  background  color
       from  first  image  is  converted  to second image color at that point.
       Only the first image of each file is combined; again, all files'  first
       images must be of exactly the same size.
```

It is in the repos for 12.04 >> 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install gifcomb
```

[Here is the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gifcomb.1.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can use imagemagick for this:

```
convert animated1.gif animated2.gif combined.gif
```

Comment: tried this and got an error message saying the second file does not exist. i put the files the other way around and again got the same error... i want to create a new .gif file that is the serial (one after another) combination of my initial two .gif files.

Comment: I was able to do it.  Need to be in imagemagick (or precede the command with magick for current versions), and need to be in the right directory (or put a full path to the image.. using tab to complete the address when typing will help ensure it shows you the file, there are no typos, and anything needing quotes is done right)

Comment: Can it combine them side by side?